# Join pandas dataframe on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two pandas dataframes like below:

df1:

```
first_11_id spending
94838485868 50
28394958384 25
93482329832 734
```

df2:

```
first_15_id      savings
948384858684932  43
283949583845488  342
934823298324312  584
```

I would like to join them on id, and as you can see the `first_15_id` contains the first 11 digits of `first_11_id`

Desired output:

```
first_15_id      savings spending
948384858684932  43      50
283949583845488  342     25
934823298324312  584     734
```

Something like `result = df2.join(df1, how = 'inner', on = ?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may

```
df2.assign(first_11_id=df2.first_15_id.astype(str).str[:11].astype(float))\
   .merge(df, on='first_11_id')\
   .drop('first_11_id', 1)
```

---

```
       first_15_id  savings  spending
0  948384858684932       43        50
1  283949583845488      342        25
2  934823298324312      584       734
```